# Compatible actionpack missing for a Rails 5.1.0rc1 to 5.1.0 migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I've been trying to migrate my Rails app from 5.1.0rc1 to 5.1.0.

This is my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'redis', '~> 3.3.3'
gem 'redis-rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 4.2.10'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.5'
gem 'jwt', '~> 1.5.6'
gem "mini_magick", '~> 4.7.0'
gem 'rack-cors', "~> 0.4.1"
gem 'mandrill-api', "~> 1.0.53"
gem 'curb', "~> 0.9.3"
gem 'inherited_resources', '~> 1.7'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'therubyracer', git: 'https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer.git'
gem 'meta-tags', '~> 2.4.0'
gem 'slim', '~> 3.0.7'
```

This is what I get from a bundle install:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.5) was resolved to 0.10.5, which depends on
      actionpack (< 6, >= 4.1)

    activeadmin (~> 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      formtastic (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.2.13)

    activeadmin (~> 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7) was resolved to 1.7.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 5.1, >= 3.2)

    rails (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.1.0)

    rails (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.1.0)

    rails (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.1.0)

    activeadmin (~> 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      ransack (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.8.2, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.0)
```

What could be wrong?

If it helps (but I doubt it), I work on a Docker container. I have deleted the `Gemfile.lock` to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Rails 5.1.0 isn't relreased yet. The latest is `5.1.0.rc2`

Comment: Ok, I thought it was because of the announcement. My bad :)

Comment: What announcement? I may very well have missed that, but it doesn't update to more than 5.1.0.rc2 on my machine

Comment: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2017/4/27/Rails-5-1-final/

Comment: Ok, interesting, it doesn't update on my machine to the final version. That must happen soon hopefully

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong at least, just have to wait a few days

Comment: good to know, thanks 

Comment: 5.1 was released on 27th and it is working. Try `bundle update`. The problem is probably one of the gems you are using doesn't support `5.1` yet. Other people also faced problem with activeadmin on 5.1 https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic gem here is `activeadmin`'s `inherited_resources`, the latest version of which specified `actionpack (< 5.1, >= 3.2)` when you asked your question.

Perhaps surprisingly, your previous release candidate version of actionpack, `5.1.0.rc1`, satisfies the `< 5.1` constraint, so you weren't blocked from upgrading to the release candidate, but were blocked from the final version.

A new version of `inherited_resources` was cut on May 3rd, which will have fixed things, but note that the current [gemspec](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources/blob/master/inherited_resources.gemspec) means you'll have the same issue when Rails goes to 5.2.